# Excel 2010: Save current tab as tab delimited txt file

Tags: microsoft-excel, r, macros

I do most of my stats in R, thus I know nothing about Excel macros and must ask for help. My institute provides MS Office 2010 (currently), so I use that to do quick edits to my data sets, then I save them as tab limited .txt files and open them in R. I use .xlsx file format, because I can save several data sets in the same file. This makes it easier to keep track of different projects.

However, Excel is excel after all. Whenever I try to save as txt file it first asks me, if want to replace the earlier txt file I have created. Then it says that the file format can't support multiple tabs and I must click "OK". As if this wasn't enough, next it asks if I really want keep the workbook in this format...and finally, after clicking half a dozen times, I have my txt file, but now I have to close it, since I don't want to edit the txt file, since I would lose these edits in .xlsx file. Well, when I close Excel, it asks if I want to save my .txt file again!

Now after 5 years of reading these warnings almost every working day, I am sick of this. I gotta find a better system. It appeared to me that maybe a macro would help.

I would like the **macro to save current tab of my .xlsx file as tab limited .txt file into the folder where the .xlsx file is located**. I want it to **use the name of the current tab as file name and overwrite any previous files with the same name**. And I want to do this with one click.

Comment: Great question.  I struggle with this too.  Is there a better forum for this?  Why the close vote?

Comment: Because xlsx package solves the problem better than any VBA macro. Just do read.xlsx("filename.xlsx", "tabname"). I was looking for this kind of package about a year ago. That time there was one, but it didn't work very well. This one seems to work better. I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I'd do:

1. Save your data in Excel format.
2. Read it into R with xlsx, RODBC or one of the other packages out there that can handle Excel.
3. Do your analysis.

If you know nothing about Excel macros, this will be a lot easier than trying to learn VBA.

I'll also add: doing it this way means you don't have to worry about formatting issues. If you save a worksheet in text format, it retains any formatting that may have been applied, eg commas or dollar signs in numbers. This will trip up R's `read.delim`, which will assume that any non-numeric characters means the variable should be treated as a factor.

Comment: Agreed. Much better than Excel macro. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this to get the data into R, where you have more control over how you save to file?

1. In Excel: Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C (Select all in current sheet, copy to clipboard)
2. In R:     x <- read.delim("clipboard")

Not exactly one click, but pretty simple nonetheless.

Comment: This doesn't work together with Notepad++ and is clumsy with large data sets